# Unix fork parent id inconsistent

Tags: c, unix, fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
    printf("I am parent! My id: %d\n", (int)getpid());

    pid_t childPIDorZero = fork();

    if (childPIDorZero == -1) {
        perror("fork() error");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (childPIDorZero == 0) {
        printf("Success. ID: %d, Parent ID: %d\n", (int)getpid(), (int)getppid());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

1-Result:

[image]

2-Result:

[image]

I don't understand this situtaion. Result 1 is true but Result 2 false but I didn't do any changes. Why are the parent ID results different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the parent never waits for the child to finish (see `man waitpid`).

As a result, the parent could terminate before the child even starts to execute, in which case the child will be [reparented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process).

The possibly interesting feature of the experiment is that the pid of the new parent is 919, and not 1 as would be expected. (As explained in the Wikipedia article, child processes without parents are given to the `init` process, which is pid 1.) However, Linux has a facility which allows a process to become a "reaper" of descendant processes, and Ubuntu enables this feature to give each user their own `init` process. See the "User Session Mode" section in `man 5 init`, if you are running a system with `upstart`.